# How to permanently delete an empty folder from a S3 bucket where versioning is enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

How to permanently delete an empty folder from a S3 bucket where versioning is enabled?

If I am selecting an empty deleted folder with "show versions" enabled, I see the "Delete" greyed out.[In the image I have selected a completely empty prefix "f1/" and delete for it is showing greyed out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0VyY.png)

Is it possible to permanently delete these folders using lifecycle policy?
I applied lifecycle policy few days ago, but that also didn't help. Any recommendation on what wrong I am doing?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZAah.png)

Comment: How many objects do you have?